# Allow Cache for only images from a specific url

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, cache-control

I want to set **cache-control: public** for images from a particular request url from action and set **cache-control: no-cache** for all other images.

Can we do add conditions in php or htaccess file? Please suggest how can I set headers conditionally for the same.

Comment: What web-server do you use?

Comment: @PrisacariDmitrii xampp

Answer (score 0):

Set following snippet in your apache config file:

```
<FilesMatch "dir_one\/\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3024000, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "dir_two\/\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

All images from directory `dir_one` will be cached. All images from `dir_two` will not be cached by users browser.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. In my case the ajax request goes to a method (function) in controller and it returns the image using php **readfile("PATH_TO_IMAGE")**
e.g. www.example.com/product/getProductImage

getProductImage() returns the image.

How can I mention this particular request from getProductImage function to be only cached?

Comment: I think you should not change `getProductImage()` in any way. It does what it does. Instead of this, after executing `getProductImage()` add a condition to check if the url matches your requirements and add response header using `header("Cache-Control: no-cache")`